# Can others see pending close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Can other users see close votes on my question if they haven't reached the threshold to close? If so, does this not bias users to vote to close more often?

Comment: Those that can vote to close can see the current count if there are votes, yes.

Comment: They can see the *number* of close votes, and which category they voted to close as, but not *who* has voted to close (until the question is actually closed).

Comment: @Servy Except in the case of the first-issued `Possible duplicate of x` vote, for whom the close voter's name is attached unless the comment gets deleted.

Comment: @meta.michael Also unless there was already a comment with a link to that question, but yes.

Comment: @Servy there are some other cases where you can see *who* has voted before the question is posted - I'll post an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes those with rep to close can, and it might.

However remember something important, even the people with close privileges aren't perfect, and seeing what the community thinks can help them learn what is or isn't acceptable.

Comment: Your answer is the same as Makoto's but I am accepting yours because of the idea that the actions of others might dictate what is acceptable (which can be good).

Answer (score 10):

[You can see others' close votes at 3,000 rep, when you can cast your own close/reopen votes.](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)

As for the bias part, I would *hope* that those who do have this privilege would close/reopen the question on the merits, not because, "Oh, this question needs only one more vote to close it."

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers state, those with the vote to close privilege can see the number of close votes a question has attracted and a breakdown of which reasons have been given.

However what hasn't been mentioned thus far is that you *can* see who has voted to close a question if that vote was cast from the close votes queue, for example on a currently still open question:

[image: Example of review queue history]

Where everyone with a "close" remark has *voted* to close the question from the review queue.  This is another edge case in a similar category to the automatic duplicate comment (though this will probably be removed very soon).

Comment: Note: That information is only available to those who have already voted while it's still in the review process. It's only made available to everyone once review is completed. Besides, it can be quite difficult for a user without access to the full history to even find those. It'd basically be a game of browsing everyone's profile who's been active on the question and looking for review events, only to find semi-useful information.

Comment: @animuson: Mods have an easy way to get to the review history of a post. Btw, any idea when a user gets to see the full review history? On the sites I mod and MSO I can see it, but on other sites I only see my reviews.

Comment: @Manishearth: You start seeing reviews of everyone once you get the 10k tools.

Answer (score 2):

There is an entire [Close Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), where users with at least 3k reputation can see questions that have either pending close votes or *it doesn't belong here* flags.

Once you click "close" in either the question or the review queue, you can see how many users have voted to close for a specific reason.

This should not bias others to vote to close. The queue itself has a <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> button; if a sufficient number of users press it, the question disappears from the queue.

Note that there's also a [Reopen Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen).

In addition, 10k users can see those and some other pending flags inside the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools). They can either vote to close or cast an *invalid flag* flag.

Without those tools, moderating the currently 4,500,000 question on Stack Overflow would be impossible. The Close Votes queue alone holds almost 50,000 questions right now.