# A low rep user identified me as voting to close before the question was closed. How is this possible?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

As I understand it, if you have only +10K rep, you can see who has voted to close before the question is closed.

Based on:

- [What can Moderators and Trusted Users see that others can't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90844/what-can-moderators-and-trusted-users-see-that-others-cant)
- [Can others see pending close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166685/can-others-see-pending-close-votes/166691#166691)
- [Why can't I see who voted to close my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387163/why-cant-i-see-who-voted-to-close-my-question)

Which are all quite old and perhaps outdated?

However, in discussing [this question](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/2090/could-a-programming-language-work-where-variables-are-only-differentiated-by-fon#2090) on [PLDI](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/tour), which is in beta, the poster could see I voted to close his question.

How is this possible?

Comment: High rep users can't see who voted to close until the question is actually closed, they can see only amount of close votes, it's said in the first link you posted here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I overreacted. He was just guessing and didn't even guess correctly.

[Should frivolous questions about esolangs be on topic?](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/476/should-frivolous-questions-about-esolangs-be-on-topic/479#comment1031_476)

Comment: How is the linked question related to your question or answer here? If it's just your honest mistake, can't see much value in the question here as well.

Comment: I was trying to link the comment where a user noted the guess was incorrect but I incorrectly linked to the question not the comment.

Comment: Fair. As a side note, please note the user that guessed who closed their question has very bad reputation across many SE sites. Already suspended in five, and overall I'd strongly advise to not engage with them. Cheers! :) (in case you want to further discuss this, better come over to [the chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/shadows-den))